# Python search for value in string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
STAT bytes 0
STAT curr_items 0
STAT total_items 0
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 0
END
```

I'm trying to get the value of curr_items, so far I've got

```
out = telnet.read_until("END")
req = re.search("curr_items", out).group(0).split()[0]
```

Which returns curr_items, how do I get the value?

Thanks

Comment: What value to yo expect to get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) matching the value to your regex:

```
>>> int(re.search("curr_items (\d+)", out).group(1))
0
```

Comment: Is this a better solution than the one submitted by khachik?

Comment: @Tom, depends on what you mean by "better". My answer uses the regex to do all the work, so I can spare a call to `split()` and a list item access. @khachik's solution supports lines with no value (since he uses `*` instead of `+` in the regex) but his list access (`.split()[1]`) will fail in that case. Both solutions are good starting points, though :)

Comment: Better = best practice in python. Thanks for your detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

`re.search("curr_items [0-9]*", out).group(0).split()[1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    req = int(re.search("(?<=curr_items)\s*([\d]*)", out).group(0))
except:
    # No value was found.
    req = defaultValue
```